# SQLite: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, json, sqlite

I read answers to question similar to this, but none worked in my case.

- I created a table with 3 columns, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE raw_data(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL, payload JSON NOT NULL);
```

Populating this table with a test data, this way works:

```
# test data 1    
timer = 12345
load = 9999

query = "INSERT INTO raw_data(timestamp, payload) VALUES(?,?)"
data = (timer, load)

try:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print(f"Error while working with SQLite: {error}")

sqlite> select * from raw_data ;
1|12345|9999
```

However, when I load a json object file and run the script, I get the above frustrating error:

- json file `test.json` (I can confirm this is a valid json object):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "497042614",
    "created_at": "2022-08-18T17:32:36.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "place_id": "00611f1548c7bdef"
    },
    "id": "1560318759969214473",
    "text": "What's your Primary School nickname?"
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560077018183630848",
      "tag": "comma-separated-keywords"
    }
  ]
}
```

- reading file and attempting to populate table:

```py
timer = 6789
f = open('test.json')
load = json.load(f)

query = "INSERT INTO raw_data(timestamp, payload) VALUES(?,?)"
data = (timer, load)

try:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print(f"Error while working with SQLite: {error}")
```

Error:

```
Error while working with SQLite: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

But what's wrong with parameter 1 here, after all its value was auto inserted in the first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing in a JSON string, you are passing in a *Python object*. There is no automatic conversion back to JSON when you do this.

You could just insert the unparsed JSON:

```
timer = 6789
with open('test.json') as f:
    json_data = f.read()

query = "INSERT INTO raw_data(timestamp, payload) VALUES(?,?)"
data = (timer, json_data)

try:
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print(f"Error while working with SQLite: {error}")
```

Internally, SQLite3 just stores a string; the `json1` extension doesn't require a column to have the `JSON` type, but it can be helpful for external applications that work with the database to be able to introspect the column type and expect JSON data.

You can [register an adapter function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_adapter) to convert, say, dictionaries and lists to a JSON string, and a separate [converter function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_converter) to turn JSON data back in to Python objects, but without such niceties, the `sqlite3` library will not do the conversion for you.